# Issue pushing to heroku after installing the devise and tiny_mce gem

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So everything was running fine with my app on heroku. I installed the devise and tiny_mce gem and set them up, everything was working great locally. I pushed the new stuff up to git, pushed it over to heroku and everything was golden.

I created a "term" model and controller with associated views. This is going to support some custom "definitions" on some words I plan to use from time to time in blog posts. After realizing my 'destroy' action wasn't working I was going to test it on my live heroku site and I went to login (using devise) on heroku and got an error, I realized that I forgot to 'heroku rake db:migrate"

So I tried to run that command so I could test everything out and I was surprised to get:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Permission denied - /app/e292cf06-5d87-46cf-8035-752874301831/home/config/tiny_mce.yml
```

So i've removed this tiny_mce.yml file (i'm doing the tiny_mce config in my posts controller). I pushed to git and made sure the file was out of my git repo as well, and then pushed over to heroku and tried to run rake db:migrate again on heroku but everything is failing the same exact way. I am not sure what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in your app - presumable the `tiny_mce` gem - is trying to write that file to disk. To see where it's coming from, use `heroku rake db:migrate --trace`. You can then inspect the code - or modify it if necessary - to see the behavior.

Your best bet may be to leave that file in place with "fake" configuration in it, even if you are not using it.

Comment: Ok, i'll make sure it exists in my app and comment out anything that is there (if it isn't already) and push to git/heroku. Thanks! I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @wputah this fixed my problem. I had a line in .gitignore for config/*.yml. I added just the two YAML files to gitignore that i didn't want copied over and that allowed config/tiny_mce.yml to be sent to git and heroku. Once I let the YAML file go over I ran rake db:migrate successfully. 

I just need to get the devise email confirmation working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Tinymce` can't be viewed after deployment in `Heroku`, so i used this gem:

```
https://github.com/trevorrowe/tinymce_hammer

rails plugin install https://github.com/trevorrowe/tinymce_hammer.git
```

And finally run the rake task after following all the instructions given in that gem.

```
rake tinymce:cache_js
```